# Explain AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager, android-loader, asynctaskloader

I don't understand what all the functions in `AsyncTaskLoader` do, such as `onCancelLoad()` and `onForceLoad()`. All the functions and the order in which they're called are not documented properly.

Say I want to download a file in the background and cancel it if requested. What purpose does `onCancelLoad()` serve when there is already  `cancelLoadInBackground()`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html#forceLoad() , http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html#cancelLoad() see both links

Comment: @PiyushGupta I've already read the documentation. No where does it say what you're supposed to do in onCancelLoad(). There is already cancelLoadInBackground() and isLoadInBackgroundCanceled().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html) explains it perfectly. None of this vital information is explained in the documentation. Especially the most important aspect that it has three states that need to be handled carefully! No wonder so many apps malfunction when you rotate the screen.

Comment: But it doesn't explain how to use`cancelLoadInBackground` and `onCancelLoad` methods.